# why if I'm posting the data to SSG-WSG API(Add Course Run) then I got the return id 2487 is always

Tags: api

I post new add course run
**why if I'm posting the data to SSG-WSG API(Add Course Run) then I got the return id 2487 is always**

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update you answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have called the mock API using the endpoint `mock-api.ssg-wsg.sg`. That's why you keep getting static response from the API.

Comment: Hi druyal96, Thanks for your answer.
So, what other endpoints can I use apart from mock-api.ssg-wsg.sg?

Comment: @triyudih Based on the [API Documentation](https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/docs/product/6kYpfJEWVb7NyYVVHvUmHi/group/374zmR5D0tQeS87eA1hrLV/api/5FkiXK236UniFUNSNHsmiI/version/6H7tGFfQQLYizvVs8Uziz1), there is this Production Base URL which you can call. But, you have to subscribe the APIs first to be able to call it.

Comment: I already subscription APIs with github account. so, the APIs I need there not available to github account, it is only to corppass account,
whether the result would be different if I post it with corppass account?